# yeast subtitution in a recipe with no water

Tags: baking, substitutions, yeast, bread

I have found [this](http://www.bbcgoodfood.com/recipes/2257/christmas-morning-spiced-bread) recipe, but I want to use dry active yeast, rather than easy blend. My question is can I proof (right word?) the yeast in the milk? and how much should I use?

Comment: Kalács (Hungarian version of challah) doesn't contain any water either, so the yeast is proofed in milk. Doesn't do it any harm that I can see. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can proof the yeast in the milk. Heat the milk gently to around 120 degrees F (use an instant read or candy thermometer to check).  I would use all the milk.

Comment: I have no thermometer, but is it roughly the same temp as I need to get water?  I am used to gauging that the old fashioned way (i.e. guessing with my fingers)

Comment: and should I use the same amount of yeast as the recipe suggests?

Comment: @Mild Fuzz - same temp as the water - should be comfortable for your fingers.  You can use the same amount (active dry is strong stuff), but it really should be about 4/3 more for a correct substitution.

Answer (score 0):

You CAN proof the yeast in the milk, but if you do, be careful not to get it too warm.  Think baby bottle on wrist temperature.

Note that if your yeast really IS Active Dry Yeast (you haven't had it above your stove for the last 3 years), you can probably just dump it in.  It might take it a little longer to come around, but yeast is very resilient.  I tend toward the overnight in the refrigerator method of bread making, longer slower growth by the yeasties.

Another thought, if you really need the yeast to move fast, you can kick it up a little bit, assuming you have yeast in bulk.  The only reason why your recipe is calling for 2 teaspoons is because that is how much comes in a packet.

Easiest is just to dump it all together and make sure that your dough has time to rise, no matter how long that takes.  When I make sourdough bread, it can be all day, but if it is alive, it always rises.

Comment: you have to be careful adding too much yeast to any bread recipe, as yeast will die off if it is acting too fast.  This is why dextrous malt is sometimes added to recipes for bread - it helps yeast act without causing overactive yeast